# I want to enter double values in Java with a dot and not a comma but I get an exception

Tags: java, input, double, java.util.scanner

Hi I started to learn java on my own a couple of days ago.
I am trying to write my first basic methods but I ran into a problem.

```
public class CollectInput {

public static void collectInput() {


        System.out.println("Collect input double data!" + "\n\n");

        CustomUserInputData CustomData = new CustomUserInputData(); 
        Scanner userDataInput = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Enter the first double value:"); 
        CustomUserInputData.setFirstDoubleData(userDataInput.nextDouble());
```

When i run this code and I enter the double value using a comma for example such as:

3,2345

There is no problem.

But when I want to enter the double value in a format such as:

3.2345

Java throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
```

What do I need to do exactly in order to take input data with a dot and not a comma?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your system default locale is one that uses `,` as a decimal separator.

Assuming you want to keep using `Scanner`, you can just set the locale to `Locale.US` with [`useLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale)). The US locale uses `.` as the decimal separator:

```
Scanner userDataInput = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
... // Code as before
```